# Convert list of strings into correct type

Tags: python, postscript

I'm trying to convert a tokenized list of strings into a list of appropriate types. This function, typeChange is called to return the appropriately typed version of the string.

My code thus far does all of the following except the last case. Is there a simple way to remedy this problem?

For instance:

```
"1" -> 1
"True" -> True
"\str" -> "\str"
"[1 2 3 4 5]" -> [1,2,3,4,5]
"[1 2 3 4 5 x]" -> [1,2,3,4,5,"x"]
```

This is the typeChange function for my Simplified PostScript interpreter.

```py
def typeChange(c):
    try:
        if '[' in c:    # checking if it is a list, for some reason can't do or ']', because ints return as a list
            retList = list(map(int, (c.strip('][').split(' '))))
            return (len(retList), retList)
        if c=='True':
            return True
        elif c=='False':
            return False
        return int(c)
    except:
        return c
```

My expected results are all working for all the provided cases except when a string/variable is inside of a list:

Expected: `'[1 x 2 3 4]'` -> `[1,"x",2,3,4]`
Actual: `'[1 x 2 3 4]'` -> `'[1 x 2 3 4]'`

Comment: How about using `map(typeChange, ...)` instead of `map(int, ...)`, if not everything in the list is necessarily an int?

Comment: If you would use python syntax to write lists (`"[1, 2, 3, 4, \"a\"]"` instead of `[1 2 3 4 a]`) you could use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the output string `'[1 x 2 3 4]'` is the same as the input string, that means the line `return c` in the `except` block is being triggered, so something in the `try` block is raising an error.

The error is in the line `retList = list(map(int, (c.strip('][').split(' '))))`, caused by doing `map(int, ...)` on a list of values which are not all numeric strings; one of them is the string `'x'`. `int('x')` throws a `ValueError`, hence the observed behaviour.

To fix this, replace `map(int, ...)` with `map(typeChange, ...)`, to recursively to map the numeric strings to ints while leaving the non-numeric strings (like `'x'`) as strings without raising an error.

Comment: I was able to deduce where the error was coming from, but did not know how to fix this. I did not even know that would work in Python. This makes a lot of sense! You're awesome, thank you!

Comment: No problem. To clarify, `c.strip('][').split(' ')` results in a list of strings, and the `map` function transforms the list by applying some function (in this case either `int` or `typeChange`) to each element of the list. You can pass any function you like into `map`, so long as it works on the individual list elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
def typeChange(c):
    try:
        if '[' in c:    # checking if it is a list, for some reason can't do or ']', because ints return as a list
            retList = [int(x) if x.isdigit() else str(x) for x in c.strip('[]').split(' ')]
            return retList
        if c=='True':
            return True
        elif c=='False':
            return False
        return int(c)
    except:
        return c

typeChange('[1 2 3 4 5 x]')
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'x']
```

So let's see the type:

```
type(typeChange('[1 2 3 4 5 x]'))
list
```

We used `str.isdigit()` to return a boolean if a string represents a number:

```
'x'.isdigit()
False
'1'.isdigit()
True
```